# How to limit digits quantity on a random String?

Tags: java, random, hex

i don't find my question or i don't know how to search about it.

My problem is:

```
private final String alfabetohexa = "0123456789ABCDEF";
private final int n = alfabetohexa.length();

Random random = new Random();

public void generarMuestras(){
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        System.out.print(alfabetohexa.charAt(random.nextInt(n)));
        System.out.println(n);
    }
}
```

I want to get a random Hex String (i want to save it in a ArrayList) with 10 digits (No more, no less) this code generate 9 digits and if I change the comparator with "i" to 4, I get 12 digits.

How can I do it?

Comment: I get "XXXXXXXXX"(9), what i want to get is "XXXXXXXXXX"(10). I don't know how to explain it better...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of printing random hex digits (3 at a time), return a `String` (and for that I recommend a `StringBuilder`). Something like,

```
private static final String alfabetohexa = "0123456789ABCDEF";
private static final int    n            = alfabetohexa.length();
private static final Random random       = new Random();
public static String generarMuestras(final int len) {
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(len);
  for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    sb.append(alfabetohexa.charAt(random.nextInt(n)));
  }
  return sb.toString();
}
```